# C# MVC : Can you make a webservice that only takes POST actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, selenium

I was wondering if you can make a MVC webservice that only has HTTP POST methods.
For instance:
I use Selenium to open a page : http://localhost/main.html from .EXE application.

then my MVC app looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult main()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Final(USER user)
    {
        saveUSER(user);
        return null;
    }
```

I just don't want MVC to open another page that the one that selenium used. I used to do this with an HttpWebRequest to the GET method, but even if I returned null, it would open a blank page AND then work out the rest of the logic.

Comment: don't you want just delete this GET method? =) And add only methods with  `HttpPost` attribute

Comment: Yes you should not provide any get method in your webservice.

Comment: So it will work if I remove the get method and only leave the post one?

Comment: @PentchoTchomakov yeap it will. When you do that the only way how to comunicate with service is call method with POST

Comment: @teovankot You actually need the Get method. It serves as an entry point for the MVC app. Although, it doesn't open a new page. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

The better way to test Post methods, services and repositories in a MVC Application is using functional or unit tests. There are nice frameworks that would help you to develop these tests.

I've been using **Nunit** to develop automated test in my work and in my own projects, the framework provide me the tools to develop functional and unit tests and runs all selenium integration tests inside him.